# Chef-solo on Windows, Win32APIError when running windows_package

Tags: chef-infra, vagrant, chef-solo

On a Windows Server 2008 R2 - Datacentre core (downloaded from [vagrantbox.es](http://www.vagrantbox.es))) VM provisioned by Vagrant, I run `chef-solo` to test my cookbook. I cannot run a `windows_package` without getting an Win32APIError.

Running the following recipe step:

```
windows_package ".NET 4.0" do
  package_name "Microsoft .NET Framework 4 Extended"
  source "http://download.microsoft.com/download/3/6/1/361DAE4E-E5B9-4824-B47F-6421A6C59227/dotNetFx40_Full_x86_x64_SC.exe"
  options "/q"
  installer_type :inno
  action :install
end
```

Yields the following error:

```
Chef::Exceptions::Win32APIError: windows_package[.NET 4.0] (<my recipe> line 10) had an error: 
 Chef::Exceptions::Win32APIError: remote_file[C:/vagrant/cache/dotNetFx40_Full_x86_x64_SC.exe] (dynamically defined) had an error: 
 Chef::Exceptions::Win32APIError: Incorrect function.
get_named_security_info(C:/vagrant/cache/dotNetFx40_Full_x86_x64_SC.exe, SE_FILE_OBJECT, 7)
 ---- Begin Win32 API output ----
System Error Code: 1
System Error Message: Incorrect function.
---- End Win32 API output ----
```

The setup file is downloaded correctly and I can run it manually from the VM console after the chef error, so I'm guessing it's some Ruby/Chef permission error...

Trying to install the [Opscode SQL Server recipe](https://github.com/opscode-cookbooks/sql_server) produces the same `get_named_security_info` error.

Any idea what is wrong??

--
Using
Chef version 11.4.4-2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Got it. Turns out the error is caused by the fact that the cache folder (where the installer is downloaded) was in the Vagrant "network shared folder" (`c:\vagrant\cache\`). Changing it to `c:\temp\cache` for example solves the `get_named_security_info()` error.

So in my chef-solo config file:

```
file_cache_path "C:/temp/cache"
```

Comment: Thank you, was blaming lack of official support for Windows Server 2003. For people googling, same error can be masked with `Chef::Exceptions::WindowsNotAdmin: file[/vagrant/foo.txt] (foo::default line 10) had an error: Chef::Exceptions::WindowsNotAdmin: can not get the security information for '/vagrant/foo.txt' due to missing Administrator privilages.`, e.g. when you add `content "bar"` to `file "/vagrant/foo.txt"`.